# UINavigationBar of PrimaryViewController changes color after being embedded in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have a `UISplitViewController` with a `primaryViewController` and `secondaryViewController` which each have a `UINavigationBar` with a black color and translucency.

In the images below, you can see the `primaryViewController`'s `navigationBar` meet with the `navigationBar` of the `secondaryViewController`. After embedding the `UINavigationControllers` of both `ViewControllers` in `UITabBarControllers`, I can see that the colors of both had been altered.

How can I prevent this from happening, or atleast make the colors of each `NavigationBar` flush with eachother? It may not appear obvious from the second screenshot, but the `primaryViewController`'s `navigationBar` looks significantly different from the `secondaryViewController` one to the point where it is as if the primaryVC navBar had its translucency removed (although it clearly hasn't since it still blurs any views underneath it.)

### Before Embedding both `UINavigationControllers` in `UITabBarController`:

[image: Original]

### After Embedding both `UINavigationControllers` in `UITabBarController`:

[image: After Being Embedded in UITabBarController]

I don't have any code to share since this was done entirely in storyboard, no subclasses and both before and after the `UINavigationControllers` were embedded in `UITabBarControllers` the properties have stayed the same. I have checked several times that the properties are identical for each set of `UINavigationController` and `UITabBarController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: This is a Bug that only occurs in the iOS Simulator as of iOS 9.3.